# Proof that Least Square Linear Interpolation has a unique solution unless all x_i are equal.

Tags: linear-algebra, algebra-precalculus, interpolation, least-squares

There is a problem in the MIT OCW 18.02 (Multiple Variable Calculus) course that could be stated in the following way.

Show that the equations:

$$
\left\{ 
\begin{array}{c}
(\sum {x_i^2})a + (\sum x_i) b=\sum {x_i y_i} \\ 
(\sum x_i)a + nb=\sum y_i
\end{array}
\right. 
$$

for the method of least squares have a unique solution, unless all the $x_i$ are equal. Explain geometrically why this exception occurs.

Hint: use the fact that for all values of $u$, we have $\sum_1^n {(x_i - u)^2} \ge 0$, since squares are always non-negative. Write the left side as a quadratic polynomial in $u$. Usually it has no roots. What does this imply about the coefficients? When does it have a root? (Answer these two questions by using the quadratic formula.)

The course assumes only basic exposition to the linear algebra, so I expect it to be solved in a simple algebraical approach without using matrix expressions ([that's how Linear Least Squares are explained in the course](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/18-02sc-multivariable-calculus-fall-2010/pages/2.-partial-derivatives/part-a-functions-of-two-variables-tangent-approximation-and-optimization/session-29-least-squares/)).

I tried two approaches and in both I get stuck:

1. In order for the system to have a unique solution the determinant of the coefficient matrix should be non-zero, thus:

$$n(\sum x_i^2) - (\sum x_i)^2 \ne 0$$

I see that it this condition fails when $x_i = x$ for all $i$ (so to say, all $x_i$ are equal).
However I cannot prove the converse.

2. Starting from the hint, if I rewrite $\sum_1^n (x_i - u)^2$ as a quadratic polynomial in $u$, I get
   $$\sum_1^n (x_i - u)^2 \\
   = \sum_1^n (x_i^2 - 2 x_i u + u^2) \\
   = \sum_1^n x_i^2 - (2 \sum_1^n x_i) u + n u^2 $$

So the discriminant is:

$$D = 4 (\sum_1^n x_i)^2 - 4 n \sum_1^n x_i^2 \\
= 4\left( (\sum_1^n x_i)^2 - n \sum_1^n x_i^2 \right) $$

and in order for the roots in $u$ to exist, it must be $D \ge 0$.

With this method I cannot understand both how it is connected with the equations and how the discriminant inequality can be resolved.

Source: see Supplemental Problems 2G-2 at the [course page](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/18-02sc-multivariable-calculus-fall-2010/pages/2.-partial-derivatives/part-c-lagrange-multipliers-and-constrained-differentials/problem-set-6/).

Comment: re (1) *"However I cannot prove the converse"* -- have you tried applying Cauchy-Schwarz?

Comment: @user8675309 thank you, I took the $(\sum u_i v_i)^2 \le (\sum u_i^2)(\sum v_i^2)$ (Cauchy-Schwarz for $\mathbb{R}^n)$ and let $u_i = x_i$ and $v_i = 1$ for all $i$, which results in $(\sum u_i)^2 \le n(\sum u_i^2)$. Moreover it's said that the equality is reached only if $\mathbf u$ and $\mathbf v$ are linearly independent, which implies that all $x_i = u_i$ are equal.

Comment: @user8675309 I guess this is the elementary proof that I was looking for and the explicit reference to Cauchy-Schwarz can be replaced by the [proof for the $\mathbb R^n$ case](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Schwarz_inequality#Rn_-_n-dimensional_Euclidean_space) which corresponds to the given hint!